# How does the ssh client find private keys?

Tags: ssh, client, private-key

github wasn't working (`ssh -vvv -T git@github.com` did not show the private key that I wanted to use). So I added

```
Host *
  IdentityFile <private key file>
```

to `~/.ssh/config`. Then it worked.

Then, for fun, I removed the above lines and restarted the ssh client. It still works. Hunh?

To my knowledge, I am not using `ssh-agent`, `git-credential-manager`, `gh`, or anything sneaky like that. So apparently the `ssh` client itself has a memory of which private keys I previously wanted to use? How is this memory managed? Can a private key be added to the client without going through the voodoo of adding config file lines that aren't apparently needed?

**Update**

I removed the known-host entry for github, closed most client processes, and tried again. Now it doesn't remember the key. So the `IdentityFile` might be needed after all. But removing a key seems to not be immediate.